# Explaining why classes are not storing and printing out entered value

Tags: c++, string, function, class, setter

Im new to classes and i have to write my own functions and variables in a class that stores rover information when it is entered and for some reason whenever I write my functions and try to call them in main they are not working. I have provided my code and Im wondering if someone can help me explain how to get the rovers data to be stored for each rover r1-r5. Thank you.

```
class Rover{

private:

    string name;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    string direction; //Use Cardinal Directions (N,S,E,W)
    int speed; //(0-5 m/sec)
    public:
    //Constructors
    //defaultRover();
    //Rover();
//Get functions
string getName();
int getXpos();
int getYpos();
string getDirect();
int getSpeed();
void getRoverData();

//Set functions
string setName();
void setXpos();
void setYpos();
void setDirect();
void setSpeed();
};
//Constructor function
/*Rover::defaultRover()
{
    xpos=0;
    ypos=0;
    direction="N";
    speed=0;
}
*/
/*
   Rover::Rover()
   {
       cout<<"Please enter the starting X-position: ";
       cin>>xpos;
       cout<<"Please enter the starting Y-position: ";
       cin>>ypos;
       cout<<"Please enter the starting direction (N,S,E,W): ";
       cin>>direction;
       cout<<"Please enter the starting speed (0-5): ";
       cin>>speed;

       cout<<endl;
   }
*/
//Getter functions
string Rover::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Rover::getXpos()
{
    return xpos;
}

int Rover::getYpos()
{
    return ypos;
}

string Rover::getDirect()
{
    return direction;
}

int Rover::getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

void Rover::getRoverData()
{
    cout<<name;
    cout<<xpos;
    cout<<ypos;
    cout<<direction;
    cout<<speed;
}

//Setter functions
string Rover::setName()
{
    cout<<"Please enter the Rover name ";
    cin>>name;

}

void Rover::setXpos()
{
    cout<<"Please enter the X-position of the Rover ";
    cin>>xpos;
}

void Rover::setYpos()
{
    cout<<"Please enter the Y-position of the Rover ";
    cin>>ypos;
}

void Rover::setDirect()
{
    cout<<"Please enter the direction of the Rover (N,S,E,W) ";
    cin>>direction;
}

void Rover::setSpeed()
{
    cout<<"Please enter the speed of the Rover (0-5) ";
    cin>>speed;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Rover r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;

    r1.setName();
    r1.getName();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this cant be your all code. where did you define the attributes? in class scope? and are you sure you did not define them static.

Comment: You say in the question that entered values are not printed, but you are not actually printing anything - perhaps you wanted to write `cout << r1.getName() << endl;` in main ?

Comment: I'd recommend going back to reading your C++ book, it would be much more beneficial for everyone.

Comment: We dont have a book. All I need is to be told how to do 1 variable and i can figure out the rest. Im using my get functions to print the variable, so when I call r1.setName(); in main, I want to enter a name of a variable and the use the r1.getName(); to print it out

Comment: `getName` returns something, it doesn't print something.

Comment: so change the returns to couts and then I will be storing the value for each rover in the correct spot and when i call the get functions it will print the variables?

Comment: int speed //(0 - 5m/sec). That's fast boyo.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule...

## getters and setters should not communicate with stdin or stdout

- getters should `return` what they're getting
- setters should assign the member to what is being passed in

Let's make a pretend class `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
  public:  
      // setters
      void set_bar(int bar) { bar_ = bar; }
      void set_baz(std::string baz) { baz_ = baz; }
      void set_boo(double boo) { boo_ = boo; }
      // getters
      int get_bar() const { return bar_; }
      std::string get_baz() const { return baz_; }
      double get_boo() const { return boo_; }
  private:
    int bar_;
    std::string baz_;
    double boo_;
};
```

The way this should be used is something like this:

```
Foo foo;
int bar;
std::cout << "Please enter bar: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> bar;
foo.set_bar(bar);
std::cout << "foo's bar is " << foo.get_bar() << std::endl;
```

You need to change a lot of code, but I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, so basically what i need to do is set new variables such as name_  for the setName(string name_) and then could help with what my setNAme would be? would it be setName(string name_){cout<< Please enter name; cin>>name_; name=name_;}

Comment: Look at my example. You can figure that one out.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am now working on it and I have another question. I have declared all my variables the way you said too and now when I have Rover r1; in main it gives me an error, this would be Foo foo, in your example